# using multiple python variables in mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use multiple variables in a mysql query in python. The first query works fine but I keep getting an error on the second query:`1064: you have an error in your sql syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right sytanx to use near ')) from database.table' at line 1`

Here is my code:

```
query = ("select count(*) from %s.%s;" % (databaseName, tableName))

cursor.execute(query)

for row in cursor.fetchall():

       print ("This is the total count: %d" % row)

query = ("select min(%s) from %s.%s;" % (columnName, databaseName, tableName))

result2 = cursor.execute(query)

for row in cursor.fetchall():

        print ("This is the min: %d" % row)
```

I am wondering why the first query works fine but the second one is throwing out a syntax error?

Comment: Where do the values of columnName, databaseName and tableName come from? Do you validate them before executing the query?

Comment: Try omitting the trailing semicolon on each statement.

Comment: I'm fishing here, but better to rule out sooner than later. It happened to me in the past. Some SQL engines need columnName to be in the following format: tableName.columnName.

Comment: If you print the query to stdout, does it look fine? Can you test the raw SQL your Python code generates?

Comment: I figured out my problem.  I had old code that I removed and I still had result2 = cursor.execute(query) by removing result2 the query seemed to work.